# What is the purpose of a macro argument that seems useless (see code below)

Tags: c, macros, bsd

In the head file queue.h of BSD system, there is the following macro

```
#define TAILQ_ENTRY(type, qual)\
struct {\
    qual type *tqe_next;        /* next element */\
    qual type *qual *tqe_prev;  /* address of previous next element */\
}
```

With above definition, one is supposed to use it like

```
struct foo {
    TAILQ_ENTRY(struct foo, ) my_list;
    //some data here
};
```

My question is: what is the purpose of macro argument "qual" here, it seems does not play any part in code generated.

Comment: Using macros for type definitions is very fishy practice in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

Well, in *your* usage, maybe it is unused, but one call can be made like

```
struct foo {
TAILQ_ENTRY(struct foo, ) my_list;
TAILQ_ENTRY(struct foo, const) my_list_too;
//some data here
};
```

where `const` is the type-qualifier.

The type qualifier can be either of `const`, `restrict`, `volatile` or `_Atomic`.